# Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content) - localhost on Mac

Tags: wordpress

My configuration
- Mac OS 10.9
- XAMPP
- ProFTPD
- WordPress 3.8.3

Unlike most other posts on the internet for the same problem, I was not on some hosting website rather on a locally hosted instance on Mac.Everytime I tried to access the site, I got the error that the server was unable to locate the wp-content directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of tweaking around, I did the following

1. Delete previous installation of WordPress and install fresh copy
2. Set the permissions on wp-content directory via termina shell using the command chmod -R 777 wp-content. This sets the permission of all underlying files and folders as well
3. I went to this link and used the solution provided here - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-update-failure-in-wordpress-27?replies=17#post-982487
4. Essentially, I added the following line at the bottom of my wp-config file - putenv('TMPDIR=' . ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'));

Vola!! it worked and I can now focus on more important things.

Comment: It is definitely not a good idea to set `wp-content` permissions to 777

Comment: definitely not need step 1. maybe you can try skipping step 2 too.

Answer (score 5):

In macOS httpd server is executed as user "daemon".
Therefore you need to change ownership of htdocs to daemon user:

```
$ sudo chown -R daemon:daemon htdocs
```

Comment: Perfect. This should be the actual answer as setting permission to 777 is a bad idea!